# How to emulate thread_local in llvm-ir?

Tags: c++, multithreading, llvm, llvm-ir, lli

The following code is currently does not work in lli:

```
//main.cpp 
extern thread_local int tls;
int main() {
    tls = 42;
    return 0;
}

//clang++ -S -emit-llvm main.cpp && lli main.ll
```

llvm-ir:

```
; ModuleID = 'main.cpp'
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

@tls = external thread_local global i32, align 4

; Function Attrs: norecurse uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  %2 = call i32* @_ZTW3tls()
  store i32 42, i32* %2, align 4
  ret i32 0
}

define weak_odr hidden i32* @_ZTW3tls() {
  br i1 icmp ne (void ()* @_ZTH3tls, void ()* null), label %1, label %2

; <label>:1                                       ; preds = %0
  call void @_ZTH3tls()
  br label %2

; <label>:2                                       ; preds = %1, %0
  ret i32* @tls
}

declare extern_weak void @_ZTH3tls()
```

It causes the following error:

```
LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: 0x55ec0e9c3a60: i64 = X86ISD::WrapperRIP 
TargetGlobalTLSAddress:i64<i32* @tls> 0 [TF=10]
   0x55ec0e9c3858: i64 = TargetGlobalTLSAddress<i32* @tls> 0 [TF=10]
In function: _ZTW3tls
```

Is there a way to emulate TLS and transform the llvm-ir to make this work ?

Would it be feasible to use a global map from thread_id to pointers and replace every occurrence of thread-local with allocator/deallocator/getter/setter ?

Are `-femulated-tls` and `-ftls-model` of any use ?

related questions:

[how to perform TargetLowering in a IR-trasformation pass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163796/how-to-perform-targetlowering-in-a-ir-trasformation-pass?noredirect=1&lq=1)

http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2017-February/109947.html

Comment: From what i understand of the `-femulated-tls` flag that basically does do what you are talking about, emulating tls using the same model GCC does to avoid explicit linker and system support.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not affecting the IR. -femulated-tls affects the targetlowering in the codegeneration stage when generating the binary.
I need a targetlowering transformation applied to my IR, not my machine code.

Comment: @Gaetano - Any resolution? If so, can you post as an answer to your own question?

Comment: @ago unfortunately not, looks like LLVM only implements TLS-emulation in the TargetLowering pass. This pass is creating assembly from IR and seem not to be available as an IR transformation. Related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163796/how-to-perform-targetlowering-in-a-ir-trasformation-pass?rq=1

Comment: @Gaetano – Have you tried to explictly specify in the IR any of the supported TLS models (e.g. `thread_local(localexec)`)?

Comment: @cornstalks added error message.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to reproduce the error. What version of LLVM is this?

Comment: I've tested it with various versions including 6.0.0 running on  a X86_64 Debian

Comment: Yeah, I can't seem to reproduce this error. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't said what the error is that you're seeing I'm assuming it's something of the form 
`LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '_ZTH3tls' which could not be resolved!`

This is a linking error, which is actually referring to the fact that `tls` is declared as having external linkage, but there isn't another definition to link to (at least that you've posted).

Replace

```
extern thread_local int tls;
```

with

```
thread_local int tls;
```

The compiler will then generate the following IR

```
@tls = thread_local global i32 0, align 4
```

If you actually need to have external linkage and use `lli`, you'll need to link the llvm files with `llvm-link` first since `lli` doesn't have the ability to link for itself.

e.g.

ext.cpp

```
thread_local int tls = 0;
```

main.cpp

```
extern thread_local int tls;
int main() {
  tls = 42;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this will generate `ext.ll` and `main.ll`. Run `llvm-link -S ext.ll main.ll > output.ll` to get the linked file and then `lli output.ll` should also work.

Let me know if that settles it.