# how to perform TargetLowering in a IR-trasformation pass?

Tags: c++, llvm, jit, lli

To provide TLS support to orcjit, I'm like to transforom llvm::Modules without TLS emulation to ones that emulateTLS and depend on a Runtime.

Similar functionality is already implemented in `TargetLowering::LowerToTLSEmulatedModel`, however it does not operate on IR.

So, how can i implement and perform this operation as an llvm::Pass ?